# how to package webapp into jar using maven

Tags: java, maven

I am developing a web application consisting of the following structure:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5DXR.png)

When i execute mvn clean package, there is no file in webapp packaged into the jar.

Comment: A "webapp into jar", I connect (lately&mostly) with [tag:spring-boot] ..or similar. Since without any ("repackaging framework")...a "java webapp" *is a .war* .(and should be declared in pom.xml: `<packaging>war</packaging>`)

Comment: web app vs maven project could really be different things, first of all is there a pom.xml in your project. If yes kindly share it in a post

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `jar` as the packaging structure , put all your static resources under `src/main/resources/static` and it will automatically get copied into the final jar when you use the command `mvn clean install`. The webapp folder structure is suitable for war deployment. When the packaging is `war` , maven will look for the `webapp` folder and copy it's contents to the resulting `war` package.